# dimple js pie chart

Tags: d3.js, dimple.js

I'd like to be able to make a pie chart via dimple js. I have the following data:

```
    var data = [{'month': monthNames[3], 'percentonsale': 60},
                {'month': monthNames[10], 'percentonsale': 90}]
```

I'd simply like two pie charts, one displaying 60% and the other 90%.  However, Dimple does not work like this.

I end up having to do the following (taken from [Dimple.js multi series bar not stacked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24655091/dimple-js-multi-series-bar-not-stacked)):

```
var explodeData = function (oldData) {
  var newData = [];
  _.forEach(data, function(row) {
    newData.push({month: row.month, salesstart: row.salesstart, percentonsale: row.percentonsale, value: .5});
    newData.push({month: row.month, salesstart: row.salesstart, percentonsale: (100 - row.percentonsale), value: .5});
  })
  return newData;
};
```

Is there some way in Dimple to make a pie chart where I just pass it a percentage and it makes a pie chart based on that?  The issue is that I'd like to graph the percent of items that are on sale.  If I have to create this dummy data, Dimple has no way to distinguish between on-sale and not on-sale, it just graphs what percent of the the data points (on-sale and the dummy on-sale) I've passed in are and this is not ideal

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't have Dimple plot a part of the pie chart without having that actually represented by the data you pass in, it cannot extrapolate the remainder. You will have to 1) add in another property to key the series off of to distinguish between "on sale" and "not on sale" :

```
var data = [
  {'month': 'march', 'percent': 60, 'type' : 'on-sale'},
  {'month': 'october', 'percent': 90, 'type' : 'on-sale'}
];
```

and 2) calculate the remainder of each by looping through your data to create the opposite row and then a chart for each :

```
data.forEach(function(d,i){
      var svg = dimple.newSvg("#chartContainer", 300, 100);
  
      var oppositeRow = { 
                'month' : d.month, 
                'type' : 'not-on-sale', //this is your series key
                'percent' : (100 - d.percent)
               };
  
      var newData = [d, oppositeRow];
      var myChart = new dimple.chart(svg, newData);
      myChart.addMeasureAxis("p", "percent");
      myChart.addSeries("type", dimple.plot.pie);
      myChart.draw();
});
```

That will give you a separate pie chart for each month, like this : [image]

If you have access to where the data is created it may be easier to edit it at that point, otherwise you will need to manipulate it in javascript to format it as needed.

This example is available here : http://jsbin.com/nuvihu/1/edit?js,output

Comment: Thanks, I've tried to upvote your answer but it will not let me

Comment: You need 15 reputation to up-vote answers but you should be able to accept the answer at any level, if it works for you. Thanks

Comment: I try to use above code but its now working ... i have created example with above code .. http://jsfiddle.net/2ybedjLo/